# Invert Xlsxwriter Conditional Formatting

Tags: xlsxwriter

Is it possible(with an argument?) to invert the colors assign by this:

`worksheet7.conditional_format('G3:G14', {'type': '3_color_scale'})`

When I apply the above code the top values are colored in 'green', the lowest in "red" but I want exactly the opposite.

Is this possible or the only way is adding custom colors?

`worksheet7.conditional_format('I3:I14',  {'type': '3_color_scale', 'min_color': "#C5D9F1", 'mid_color': "#8DB4E3", 'max_color': "#538ED5"})`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible (with an argument?) to invert the colors assigned ... or the only way is adding custom colors?

You will need to add custom colors. That is how Excel does it, there isn't any "reverse" command in the Excel interface or in the file format, for this type of conditional format.

The colors you need are:

- '#63BE7B'
- '#FFEB84'
- '#F8696B'

Comment: Thank you @jmcnamara!